# Cocoapods downgrades dependencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

Somehow every time I run pod install or pod update, my project dependencies are downgraded. 
And if I explicitly write the project version, the pod install does not work.

Running the same pod file on another computer works fine.

Here is my pod file and my command line screen.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use. 
`$ pod setup`